# Where does the subcontinental usage of 'one' to mean 'named' come from?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, dialects, subcontinental-english

Sometimes, when reading texts published in India, written by authors of Indian origin, I notice a usage of the word *one* in the sense of 'named,' or 'is called.' For instance, it's present in this quote from Devdutt Pattanaik's *Olympus*, published in 2016:

> The story of Minos's vengeance comes from the second-century work *Bibliotheca* (meaning 'library'), a vast collection of Greek myths written by one Apollodoros.

I've also seen it in older books and news articles from the '60s and the '70s, mainly by authors who have lived in India or other parts of the subcontinent for their whole lives.

Now, this usage *is* included in many dictionaries, including [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one#Adjective), [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one), and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/one). Oxford defines it best; per the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, 'one' as a determiner is

> used before a name to denote a person who is not known to the reader to hearer; a certain  : *he worked as a clerk for one Mr. Ming*.

This is useful, but not terribly insightful. It does not have a usage note, unfortunately, which leaves me wondering: Where did it come from? Was it a usage that began in and is limited to the subcontinent? (I doubt it, as none of the Indian languages I know use similar constructions.) Or is it something brought in by the British, adopted by the subcontinent, and eventually died off in the rest of the Anglosphere? Would a native speaker without prior exposure to the usage reading the quote above consider it correct, or would they have to re-read it and scratch their head about it? Is it a declining usage, even in the Indian subcontinent? Am I wrong that it's limited to the subcontinent; is it present in other regions' English as well?

---

A few notes on the Oxford definition- I've never, ever, heard it in spoken English, as 'hearer' implies, although it's certainly possible that it is used so in other places.

Also, it's not quite the same as 'a certain'. [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20certain) definition for 'a certain' reads

> used with the name of a person one does not know : *In 1889, a certain Mr. Kelly made a large donation to the church.

Yes, 'a certain Mr. Kelly' could have been changed to 'one Mr. Kelly,' and, yes, the definition is similar, and yes, they do have the same function, but I think that 'a certain's' meaning is shifting to an almost ironic sense and refers to someone famous, as in 'That imoverished young man was none other than a certain Mr. Andrew Carnegie,' or 'as a child, she lived right next-door to a certain Lionel Messi." The usage of 'one' is not like that- it has always, in my experience, functioned as a way to tell the reader: "this is the person's name, you likely haven't (and aren't expected to have) heard of them before, it's not important that you remember it, and this name isn't going to come up again. I would say that 'one' is best replaced with, or equivalent to, 'named.' I've done some research online and can't really find much of use.

---

A few more supplementary examples:

1. His eighth-standard maths teacher was one Mr Ragavendran.
2. The son was married to the merchant's daughter, one Anahita.
3. This work was done by the peon, one Raju, who wore a grey uniform every day.

Note that the sentences would remain grammatical, even if the 'one' were removed, although I would remove the commas were you to replace it with 'named.'

Comment: It's unusual, formal, perhaps dated, but far from unknown in the UK. [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one) has: **formal** [determiner ...] :
used before the name of someone who is not known:
_Her solicitor is one John Wintersgill_. Defining using a synonym is always risky. But the wry usage of 'one' paralleling that of 'a certain' is also known.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , huh. Would you say that it's a declining trend in the UK?

Comment: I always interpreted "one X" as an abbreviation of "someone called X". I see it as analogous to Romance languages using an adjective to mean a person or thing that the adjective describes, e.g. in Spanish "un viejo" could mean "an old man" in the right context. As for its relation to "a certain", I would say they differ only by connotation, in that "a certain" conveys an air of unfamiliarity or even skepticism, while "one" is more neutral. I would be very interested to see an authoritative etymology for these constructs in English.

Comment: It is dated and Dickens is full of it. For example.

Comment: Using _one_ in this manner is equivalent to using _a certain_. They both indicate that the individual person or thing is somehow significant, perhaps unusual, and may appear later in the discourse.

Comment: A humorous story was told during the 'English' Civil War - Sir Arthur Aston, an unpopular Governor of Oxford, lost his leg in an accident. Later, Col William Legge became governor. Allegedly, people asking "Who is the new Governor?" were told "One Legge,", and replied "What, is he Governor again?"

Comment: @JohnLawler , in my experience, 'one' is not equivalent to 'a certain'; to me, 'one' means that the person _isn't_ significant. Perhaps there's a difference between the Western usage and the subcontinental usage?

Comment: [This Google 3-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+John+Smith&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) would seem to indicate that the usage is becoming less common. There are repeats and false positives masking the true trend, but the later tokens seem to be almost all references to historical works or from the legal domain.

Comment: This is normal usage in American English. "The report was filed by one Mr. Smith" sounds fine to me; it indicates that the "Mr. Smith" in question is completely unknown (and thus possibly suspicious or unreliable).

Comment: I don't know about the 'subcontinental' part (it may have a different connotation there than I am used to (AmE)). But it always sounds like a police procedural or a children's novel, trying to make the person sound pretentiously like a 'person of interest'.

Comment: Yeah, the example "one Apollodorus" suggests that the Apollodorus in question is not widely known or previously mentioned, but it also makes Apollodorus sound like a potential miscreant.

Comment: @Mitch Connotations like that are very likely to be cultural, so the nuance might not exist in Indian English. These kinds of things can be quite confusing to travelers.

Comment: All of your authors-of-Indian-origin examples need expanded context in order to evaluate. To my mind, @JohnLawler is correct; it's a certain someone, the one-of-a kind, Exhibit A ("this here"), the self-proclaimed, the in/famous person.

Comment: "One Plato" (i.e. some random person called Plato) would contrast with "*the* Plato", "*the* Pele", etc, meaning the famous one or unique one.

Comment: The British? Like…'one Sanjay Patel,' but for nearly everyone. Probably not Charlie Chan, or Holmes/Watson, but who knows.

Comment: Where did anyone get the idea this is 'subcontinental' - fairly clear to me but not recognised by Google! - dated or unusual? Some might say 'a certain' was pompous, others merely more formal.

I suggest you're confusing yourself by thinking 'one Apollodoros' means 'named Apollodoros', which it clearly does not.

'One Apollodoros' means 'a man named Apollodoros' and grammatically could also mean 'a person/woman…'

What would be wrong with 'Do you know anyone named Apollodoros'?